# Prevent app from running on two instances

Tags: java, android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

I just recently added the capability of my app to check for updates on our local server (this app is not published in the Google Play store. It's going to be used internally and there is no internet connection where it will be used. Don't ask. That's how it is :) ). I keep track of updates by checking a certain table in SQL Server and if my app's version is lower than what is indicated in this table, I download the new APK from an internal website (LAN only) then install the APK. I also have another application in the device that listens for PACKAGE_ADDED broadcasts. I can capture the broadcast successfully.

The problem is, after installation, the broadcast receiver starts the app by calling the following.

```
public class PackageInstalledBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
private final String MY_PACKAGE_NAME = "com.company.packagename";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED)) {
        String packageName = intent.getData().getSchemeSpecificPart();
        if (packageName.equalsIgnoreCase(MY_PACKAGE_NAME)) {                                
            Intent i = new Intent();
            i.setClassName(MY_PACKAGE_NAME, MY_PACKAGE_NAME + ".LoginActivity");
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(i);
        }
    }
}

}
```

But it takes a long time for the app to start. The user might think that nothing is happening, so he/she can start the app manually by clicking the app's icon. If the user clicks the app's icon, the app starts immediately. After a while, the activity that the broadcast receiver started is also opened. So now, I end up with two instances of my app in the same activity (LoginActivity). I can say that this is the case, because if I press the Back key on the device from the LoginActivity, I still end up in another LoginActivity and if I press the Back key again, I end up on the device's desktop.

Comment: If you broadcast intent to open your app LoginActivity then is your opening actually or you need to click app icon to open app.

Comment: The Activity actually opens, it just takes about 15 seconds to open after installation of update

Comment: Have you tried with other devices as well

Comment: I tried it in another device and the app opens as soon as the installation is complete. Might be a problem with the other device

Answer (score 0):

You have two problem in your question:

The fist, why your `BroadcastReceiver` take a long time to start your activity.

It have not enough information for stoving this.

The second your want to make your activity have a single instance.

Android provide a way to do that:

- Step one: Visit your application `androidmanifest` file
- Step two: Find your activity declaration.
- Step there: Add the following property `android:launchMode = "singleInstance"`

[The reference here:](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode)

P/s: If you could provide my some more information of your fist problem. Please create a new question. Hope you resolve it.

Comment: The suggestion to the 2nd problem did not work correctly. The LoginActivity does not open if the user is still in the LoginActivity. But if the user has already logged in, he/she will be in the MainActivity, Since there is no longer an instance of the LoginActivity, a new instance is being created.